# Trouble overriding contact form

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.6

I'm trying to override the contact form. I've got two trouble:

1. In `mytemplate/html/com_contact/contact` I've copied and renamed

   > - default.php
   > - default_address.php
   > - default_articles.php
   > - default_form.php
   > - default_links.php
   > - default_profile.php

   to

   > - example.php
   > - example_address.php
   > - example_articles.php
   > - example_form.php
   > - example_links.php
   > - example_profile.php

   Joomla show me the layout `example` in admin but it doesn't make any difference in the front.
2. I've made an override in `mytemplate/html/layouts/joomla/form/renderfield.php` it doesn't make any diferrence too. I've noticed in `components/com_contact/layouts/joomla/form` another `renderfield.php`, which is the one applying to the contact form.
   I've got two questions/

   1. Why **com_contact** is not using the common `renderfiel.php` and the common `renderlabel.php` is used?

      How do I override this `renderfield.php`?

Does anyone any clues about that?

I hope you will forgive my poor english.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you were copied the wrong file + wrong target folder too.

To override the com_contact you need to copy the file

> .../components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default.php

to

> ../templates/your_template_name/html/com_contact/contact/default.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that exactly what i did.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your browser dev tools. Most good templates will output the current view as a class to the `<body>` element which will confirm that you are looking at the correct view, e.g.:

[image]

Alternatively, disable SEF URLs in the site settings and the full path will be present in the URL.

If you are indeed seeing the correct view, i.e. from your template override, but not seeing your changes appear then you may be looking at cache. Disable caching in J! Admin and clear the cache then hard reload your browser.

Comment: Thank you but I've checked those points. I've added a class .test to default and it's default that applying

Answer (score 0):

Try copy default.xml file as well (and rename), I think that it needs to be in override folder in order to override function properly.

Answer (score 0):

I experience exactly the same. Additionally, if I place the adjusted override file back in the orignal tmpl folder (and rename it to default.php) the intended changes do occur.

Furthermore, the changes in the sub-files (i.e. default_articles.php) also in my_template/html/com_contact/ are handled correctly. So:

- default override doesn't work
- sub file override does work...